# Raised to the multiple of 3

Tags: java

I was assigned to write a program that would be able to produce this in java.

```
+-----+-----------+ 
|   n | n * n * n | 
+-----+-----------+ 
|   1 |         1 | 
|   2 |         8 | 
 . . .       . . . 
|  20 |      8000 |
+-----+-----------+
```

I am having an issue with coming up with a for loop that will be able to list 1 to 20 on one side and 1 to 20 being raised to the third power.

Comment: For questions like this you should show your attempt at solving the problem and the actual output you are getting.

Comment: My issue is that I don't even know how to make the for loop for this question

Comment: Do you have to produce those fancy borders as well?

Comment: No I don't need to produce the fancy borders

Comment: If you know how to print `n` and you know how to find the cube of `n` then I do not understand what the problem is. Can you be specific?

Comment: I only need it to produce a list of 1 through 20 and another list of 1 through 20 all being raised to a power of 3. I don't know how to print n or how to find the cube of n

Comment: Use one loop and print them side by side, separated by a space.

Comment: I don't know how to make the loop and print them side by side

Comment: Go through your books or watch tutorials online. Then try something out and if something doesn't work ask again.

Comment: Printing and finding cube are two separate problems. Try to solve them one by one. Lets say that I have `int i = [somevalue];`, try to fill the gap which will let us know the cube of it `int iCube = ....`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help ***must*** include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult for me to give general help without giving the explicit answer. Your code will look something (very very similar) to this.

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
  // print n
  // print n cubed
}
```

So really, if you know how to print a variable, and print a variable * itself * itself, you should be in good shape.

Comment: It's good that you didn't hand them the code, and instead gave them the opportunity to understand the problem